# Name value pair list, unable to increment name width number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create this using a for loop.

```
            slideArr.slide1 = 1;
            slideArr.slide2 = 2;
            slideArr.slide3 = 3;
```

So I get my total slides, loop over them like so

```
            for ( index = 0; index < totalSlides.length; ++index ) 
            {
                slideArr.slide = index;
            }
```

but I want the name value pair name in the case "slide" to increment as well.

```
            for ( index = 0; index < totalSlides.length; ++index ) 
            {
                slideArr.slide1 = 1;
            }
```

and on the second loop

```
            for ( index = 0; index < totalSlides.length; ++index ) 
            {
                slideArr.slide2 = 2;
            }
```

..etc..

is this possible?

I'm basically creating a name value pair list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would highly advise **against** solutions recommending `slideArr["slide"+index]`. This is a [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and in this case it suggests you're doing something wrong. Posting your full code would help others give you better, more precise answers.

First, `slideArr`, to me, implies you're using an `Array` datatype, but you're treating it more like an Object when you call

```
slideArr.slide1 = 1;
```

If it's actually an Array, this would be pretty bad

```
// Don't use arrays like this !
var slideArr = [];
slideArr.slide1 = 1;
```

**Instead**, if you have an *Object* containing an array of slides, that might be a little better

```
// Use an object with an array !
var myData = {slides: []};

// Add some slides
myData.slides.push(1);
myData.slides.push(2);
myData.slides.push(3);
```

Now you have an array of slides within `myData`

```
console.log(myData.slides);
// => [1, 2, 3]
```

You can loop through that quite easily

```
for (var i=0; i<myData.slides.length; i++) {
  console.log(myData.slides[i]);
}
```

Output

```
1
2
3
```

---

If you know the slides up front, you can define `myData` all in one go

```
var myData = {slides: [1, 2, 3]};
```

You can skip the `.push` calls above. Looping stays the same and you'll get identical output.

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped for the problem and my understanding. Sorry I couldn't upload the code. Would it be incorrect to create name value pairs this way, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
slideArr["slide" + index] = index;
```

but I would like to add this looks weird. Are you sure this is what you want?

How about:

```
slideArray.slides.push(totalSlides[i]);
```

Comment: What's weird about this `slideArr["slide" + index] = index`?

Comment: The keys seem meaningless. How are you going to retrieve them? Using a for-in? Would an array suffice then?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for ( index = 0; index < totalSlides.length; ++index ) 
{
    slideArr["slide" + index] = index;
}
```

Comment: -1 This answers the question in a harmful way. You've supplied the OP with an immediate solution but taught him/her nothing about proper programming.